# Numpy installation fails when installing with Poetry on M1 and macOS

Tags: python, numpy, python-poetry

I have a Numpy as a dependency in Poetry `pyproject.toml` file and it fails to install.

```
  error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
              error: Command "clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.sdk -DNPY_INTERNAL_BUILD=1 -DHAVE_NPY_CONFIG_H=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DNO_ATLAS_INFO=3 -DHAVE_CBLAS -Ibuild/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.9/numpy/core/src/umath -Ibuild/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.9/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.9/numpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.9/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/Users/moo/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/dex-ohlcv-qY1n4duk-py3.9/include -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -Ibuild/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.9/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.9/numpy/core/src/npymath -c numpy/core/src/multiarray/array_assign_scalar.c -o build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-3.9/numpy/core/src/multiarray/array_assign_scalar.o -MMD -MF build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-3.9/numpy/core/src/multiarray/array_assign_scalar.o.d -faltivec -I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers" failed with exit status 1
              [end of output]
        
          note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
          ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
        Failed to build numpy
```

- macOS Big Sur
- Python 3.9 installed through Homebrew

How to solve it?

If I install Numpy with pip it installs fine.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Make sure you have OpenBLAS installed from Homebrew:

```
brew install openblas
```

Then before running any installation script, make sure you tell your shell environment to use Homebrew OpenBLAS installation

```sh
export OPENBLAS="$(brew --prefix openblas)" 
poetry install
```

If you get an error

```
                File "/private/var/folders/tx/50wn88yd40v2_6_7fvfr98z00000gn/T/pip-build-env-uq7qd2ba/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 252, in get_tag
                  plat_name = get_platform(self.bdist_dir)
                File "/private/var/folders/tx/50wn88yd40v2_6_7fvfr98z00000gn/T/pip-build-env-uq7qd2ba/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 48, in get_platform
                  result = calculate_macosx_platform_tag(archive_root, result)
                File "/private/var/folders/tx/50wn88yd40v2_6_7fvfr98z00000gn/T/pip-build-env-uq7qd2ba/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wheel/macosx_libfile.py", line 356, in calculate_macosx_platform_tag
                  assert len(base_version) == 2
              AssertionError
```

This should have been fixed in the recent enough Python packaging tools.

Make sure

- Poetry is recent enough version
- Numpy is recent enough version
- Any dependency using Numpy, like Scipy or Pyarrrow are also the most recent version

For example in your `pyproject.toml`

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
# For Scipy compatibility
python = ">=3.9,<3.11"

scipy = "^1.8.0"
pyarrow = "^7.0.0"
```

Even if this still fails you can try to preinstall `scipy` with `pip` before running `poetry install` in Poetry virtualenv (enter with `poetry shell`) This should pick up the precompiled scipy wheel. When the precompiled wheel is present, Poetry should not try to install it again and then fail it the build step.

```sh
poetry shell
pip install scipy
```

```
Collecting scipy
  Downloading scipy-1.8.0-cp39-cp39-macosx_12_0_arm64.whl (28.7 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 28.7/28.7 MB 6.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<1.25.0,>=1.17.3 in /Users/moo/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/dex-ohlcv-qY1n4duk-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from scipy) (1.22.3)
Installing collected packages: scipy
Successfully installed scipy-1.8.0
```

After this run Poetry normally:

```
poetry install
```

Comment: @mikko-ohtmaa thanks for the helpful answer.  Wondering if you might share how you discovered this was the problem?

Comment: A discovered it with a lot of cursing

Comment: Worked for me also for the same error in another project. Thank you :D